# generating ids for JSON elements

Tags: javascript, random, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way to generate a random id (javascript preferred) via this format:?

7181cec4-cf43-5936-a75b-c1d5f8a7e00e

I need to create an id for each element in a JSON file in order to differentiate them when doing all kinds of sorting.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function randomAlphaNumeric () {
    return Math.random().toString(36).charAt(2);
};

function createFromPattern (pattern) {
    pattern = pattern.split('');
    return pattern.map(x => x.replace('x', randomAlphaNumeric())).join('');
};
```

Will allow you to create your ID in whichever pattern you like, as long as it's in the format `xxx-xxx`

Example:

```
createFromPattern('xxx-xxx')
> "e6y-gzc"
createFromPattern('xxx-xxx-x-xxx-xxxx')
> "3w8-fch-t-fh3-h4uu"
createFromPattern('x-xxx-x')
> "c-yli-4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
<script>
    function RandomHexString(L) {
        var hexstring='';
        for(var i=0; i<L; i++) {
            hexstring+=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
        }
        return(hexstring);
    }

    console.log(RandomHexString(8) + '-' + RandomHexString(4) + '-' + RandomHexString(4) + '-' + RandomHexString(4) + '-' + RandomHexString(12));   
</script>
```

This will produce outputs like:

```
a007bfd5-7883-6ac4-2a35-57efa2ab6fdc
7428b81f-4670-64ce-e02b-2ac97ae241bc
```